# Custom menu linking to page not found

Tags: menus, errors

I have built a series of pages and sub pages in wordpress.

Then, using custom menus with 5 x top level menus and then sub-menus under 3 of these top level menus:

```
Menu 1
Menu 2
- Sub Menu 1
- Sub Menu 2
Menu 3
Menu 4
- Sub Menu 1
- Sub Menu 2
- Sub Menu 3
- Sub Menu 4
Menu 5
- Sub Menu 1
- Sub Menu 2
```

Whenever I click on Menu 5 -> Sub Menu 1 OR Sub Menu 2 I get "Nothing Found for: Sub Menu 1"

I've just gone back into the page editor and clicked "View Page" and I get the same error.  The pages I've created cannot be viewed.
I can view all other Sub Menu Pages in all other menus except the last menu.

I thought the url might be too long but it is no longer than any other URL in any other sub menu?

ANy Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The menu name was "Search" so wordpress redirected the subpages to the wordpress search results page and was assuming the search functionality.

Comment: Please explain that with more details, and mark your question as _answered_ afterwards.